# fatal error: ros/ros.h: No such file or directory 1 | #include "ros/ros.h"

Tags: c++, cmake, ros

There are a lot of questions related to this, but I could not find anything that useful to me. I created a c++ script to subscribe to a camera topic. when I tried to run the script I get the following error.

```
receiver.cpp:1:10: fatal error: ros/ros.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "ros/ros.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

and as per I searched the internet the error is due to the CMake file. I tried various ways could not figure out why. so I have also added my CMake list file below. kindly look into it.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(cv_basics)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  roscpp
  rospy
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  nav_msgs
)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
# add_message_files(
#   FILES
#   Message1.msg
#   Message2.msg
# )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
# add_service_files(
#   FILES
#   Service1.srv
#   Service2.srv
# )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
#generate_messages(
 #  DEPENDENCIES
  # sensor_msgs#   std_msgs
# )



catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES cv_basics
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS cv_bridge image_transport roscpp rospy sensor_msgs std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
 include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

i am using ros noetic, and ubuntu 20

Comment: Have you sourced your ROS environment?

Comment: Your cmake file doesn't actually build anything. Is this the whole file?

Comment: @DoritoJohnson yes its the complete cmake file

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg yes i did

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you're building with the ros libraries in your `CMakeLists.txt` file. Make sure you have these lines:

```
add_executable(some_exe src/your_source.cpp)
target_link_libraries(some_exe ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

Of course, replace `some_exe` and `src/your_source.cpp` with their correct respective names in your package.

Comment: i have added the following lines now. `add_executable(frame_listener src/receiver.cpp)
target_link_libraries(frame_listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
`
but when I try to catkin_make my workspace I get the following error.
` *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so.4.2.0', needed by '/home/akash-j/catkin_ws/devel/lib/cv_basics/frame_listener'.  Stop.
`